# Update menu in telegram bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-telegram-bot-api

I have a bot that he only show the user a menu. Written using node-telegram-bot-api.
I have updated the links in the menu and I want to update all the users to the new menu without clicking "start" again.

I tried resetting the bot and deleting botdata but it didn't send the menu again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save somewhere the `message_id` along with the `chat_id` fields that you'll receive in the reply whenever you send a message, for every chat where the message got sent and then call the method `bot.editMessageReplyMarkup` with the appropriate parameters (like `message_id`).
But caution: if the user blocked the bot or deleted the chat, you'll receive an error. So you'll have also to delete the current `message_id` from your records if this will happen.